# Does Python have a particular term for slicing a list element?

Tags: python, slice

```
g = ["01", "05", "95", "99"]
x = g[0][:1]
print x
```

I was coding strings and slices, like above, and I was wondering if the double brackets had a particular Pythonic name (manly to differentiate the two sets of parenthesis)? Or is it just called a sliced element?

Comment: Nope, it's just a slice of an element.

Comment: `(g[0])[:1]` = `something[:1]`. The fact that sliceable object is a result of another slice is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about this. `g[0]` returns an item that is itself sliceable; it's just short for

```
g1 = g[0]
x = g1[:1]
```

or

```
x = g.__getitem__(0).__getslice__(None, 1)
```

or

```
x = g.__getitem(0).__getitem__(slice(None, 1))
```

(Not that you would ever call the magic methods directly, but it helps to show that the second set of brackets is applied to the result of the first set; they do not both apply directly to `g`.)